# psPAS loop not working, how do I loop through a test file?

Tags: powershell, cyber-ark

I have this ps1 script that works for a single safe.

```
$AccountsDetails = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$accounts = Get-PASAccount - safeName RESEARCH_MAINT


if ($accouonts -eq $null -or $accounts.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No accounts retrieve from the safe."
    }

foreach ($account in $accounts) {
        $AccountsDetails.add((Get-PASAccountDetail -id $account.id)) | Out-Null
        }
        
        $LockedAccountsInfo = @()
        
foreach ($AccountDetail in $AccountsDetails.Details) {
        if ($AccountDetail.LockedBy -notin "",$null) {
            $LockedAccountsInfo += @{
                Username = $AccountDetail.RequiredProperties.Username
                safe = $AccountDetail.safeName
                LockedBy = $AccountDetail.LockedBy
                }
            }
        }
if ($LockedAccountsInfo.Count -eq 0) {
    write-host "No locked accounts were found"
    return
    } else {
            write-host "$(LockedAccountsInfo.Count) locked account(s) found."

$filePath = "c:\test.txt"
foreach ($lockedAccount in $LockedAccountsInfo) {
    $line = "Username: $($LockedAccount.Username), LockedBy: $($LockedAccount.LockedBy), Safe: $($LockedAccount.Safe)"
    $line | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append -Encoding UTF8
    
Write-Host "Locked accounts information has been saved to $filePath."
```

Instead of finding just one safe, I have a txt file with a list of safes that I want it to loop through. I've modified it to be this script instead

```
"# Initialize an ArrayList to store details of all accounts from all safes
$AllAccountsDetails = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# Specify the path to the .txt file containing the list of safes
$safesFilePath = "c:\path\to\safes.txt"

# Read the list of safes from the .txt file
$safes = Get-Content -Path $safesFilePath

# Iterate through each safe listed in the file
foreach ($safeName in $safes) {
    # Retrieve accounts from the current safe
    $accounts = Get-PASAccount -safeName $safeName

    # Check if the accounts retrieval returned null or an empty collection
    if (-not $accounts -or $accounts.Count -eq 0) {
        # Inform the user no accounts were retrieved from the current safe
        Write-Host "No accounts retrieved from safe: $safeName."
    } else {
        # Loop through each account retrieved and add its details to the ArrayList
        foreach ($account in $accounts) {
            $null = $AllAccountsDetails.Add((Get-PASAccountDetail -id $account.id))
        }
    }
}

# Initialize an array to hold information about locked accounts
$LockedAccountsInfo = @()

# Iterate over the account details to find any locked accounts
foreach ($AccountDetail in $AllAccountsDetails) {
    # Check if the account is locked by someone
    if ($AccountDetail.LockedBy -notin @("", $null)) {
        # If locked, add the relevant details to the LockedAccountsInfo array
        $LockedAccountsInfo += @{
            Username = $AccountDetail.RequiredProperties.Username
            Safe     = $AccountDetail.SafeName
            LockedBy = $AccountDetail.LockedBy
        }
    }
}

# Check if any locked accounts were found
if ($LockedAccountsInfo.Count -eq 0) {
    # Inform the user if no locked accounts were found
    Write-Host "No locked accounts were found."
} else {
    # Display the count of locked accounts found
    Write-Host "$($LockedAccountsInfo.Count) locked account(s) found."

    # Specify the file path where the information will be saved
    $filePath = "c:\path\to\lockedAccountsInfo.txt"
    # Loop through each locked account and append its details to the file
    foreach ($lockedAccount in $LockedAccountsInfo) {
        $line = "Username: $($lockedAccount.Username), LockedBy: $($lockedAccount.LockedBy), Safe: $($lockedAccount.Safe)"
        # Use Add-Content for appending to ensure each line is added without overwriting existing content
        Add-Content -Path $filePath -Value $line -Encoding UTF8
    }

    # Inform the user that the locked accounts information has been successfully saved
    Write-Host "Locked accounts information has been saved to $filePath."
}
"
```

I'm getting an error. that i can't figure out.
"Invoke-PASRestMethod : [400] The format of the given filter is not supported.
At line: 190 char: 13
$$result = Invoke-PASRestMethod -Uri $URI -Method GET -WebSession $$..."

Modify first code to loop through a text file for the safes and get the locked account in each safe.

Comment: You are making an HTTP Connection and the returned status is 400 which means Bad Request.  So the connection is completing and then the server is finding an issue with the request.  An HTTP Connection has 3 parts 1) URI 2) HTTP Headers 3) Body/Content.  Error 400 means there is something wrong with either the Headers, or Body, or the Headers are not consistent with the body.  I would make sure your code match the following : https://pspas.pspete.dev/commands/Get-PASAccount